# Identify seasonality using 1 year period

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data set which represents the number of customers subscribing monthly from Dec2018. I would like to check if i have seaosnality in my data however, am getting an erro in R.

```
    Month   Subs
1  201812   37551.17
2  201901   42144.39
3  201902   37466.42
4  201903   37568.11
5  201904   35271.50
6  201905   49453.71
7  201906   60640.16
8  201907   59835.07
9  201908   71657.11
10 201909   71911.35
11 201910   57962.19
12 201911   55538.46
13 201912   59423.75
14 202001   62707.65
15 202002   50034.92
```

In `R` I have done the below where the following error where prompted:

```
> myts <- ts(data = Data$DBRollOver, start =c(2018,12),frequency=12)
> fit <- stl(myts,s.window = "period")
Error in stl(myts, s.window = "period") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error is clear. You only have 1 period, so how is it supposed to capture the periodicity...?

Comment: yes exactly so is there a way that I detect if there is seasonality in just one period? @sotos

Comment: How would you define 'seasonality' with just one period (i.e. 'season')? Are you maybe thinking of something else (e.g. literal seasons, like spring, summer, etc)?

Comment: @dario - I want to see if it is possible to find seasonality with 1 year worth of data or not? so for example during summer we get more people on board

Comment: Please read [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/)